# Pass data into createPages API from gatsby-node.js

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I want to pass data in the form of variables into my react components when using gatsbyjs

I can generate pages at a different URL's but I want each one to have access to data outside of the GraphQL query. I am aware that context passed to GraphQL but I don't want to do this.

For example using this I can create a page called localhost/my-page using a react component. However inside the component I fetch data from another server using AJAX and I need to pass a search query to my props inside the create page.

How do I do this please?

```
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators }) => {
const { createPage } = boundActionCreators

const component = path.resolve('src/pages/demo-photos.js')

const pages = [ 'one' ].map(name => ({
  id: `page-${name}`,
  path: `/${name}`,
  component,
  layout: `index`,
  context: {
      searchtag: `${name}`, // I WANT THIS AVAILABLE INSIDE MY REACT COMPONENT
  }
}))

pages.map(p => createPage(p))
}
```

Comment: `searchtag` should come into your component as `props.pathContext.searchtag`.  does it not?

Comment: pathContext worked like charm. Saved my day. Thanks:)

Comment: Hi, would you mind giving an example of how you use pathContext?

Comment: something that tripped me up here is that, when you modify the return value of createPage, you then must restart the gatsby local dev server to see those changes reflected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Gatsby to work correctly, I believe that Gatsby needs to fetch all of your data. Gatsby grabs all your data, builds its own internal data model, and then writes that to JSON files which are part of the static build. That's why Gatsby can pre-fetch pages before a user clicks on them. If you add your own custom data fetching inside of a page, that data cannot be pre-fetched by Gatsby because it doesn't know where the data comes from.

So the solution is probably to build your own source plugin to pull the external API data into Gatsby, and then use the "normal" Gatsby flow to get that data into your components. This might help https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/create-source-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

The data you pass into the `context` property in `gatsby-node.js` is available via `props.pageContext` in the template component(the component you use to generate pages on-the-fly)